# A view consisting of user's first and last posts

Tags: views

I setup to create a view that would show me all users, their total post counts. Now I need to show when their first post was made and when their last post was made. I have included an export of my current view. Any help would be welcome.

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'user_node_counts';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'User Node counts';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Number Of Posts';
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  3 => '3',
  7 => '7',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'counter' => 'counter',
  'name' => 'name',
  'points' => 'points',
  'field_phone' => 'field_phone',
  'type_1' => 'type_1',
  'type' => 'type',
  'uid' => 'uid',
  'php' => 'php',
  'created' => 'created',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'counter' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'name' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'points' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_phone' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'type_1' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'type' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'uid' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'php' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'created' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['override'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['sticky'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['empty_table'] = 0;
/* Relationship: Content: Author */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['required'] = 0;
/* Field: Global: View result counter */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['id'] = 'counter';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['field'] = 'counter';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['label'] = '#';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['more_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['counter_start'] = '1';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['more_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_user'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['overwrite_anonymous'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['format_username'] = 1;
/* Field: Userpoints total: Current total money */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['id'] = 'points';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['table'] = 'userpoints_total';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['field'] = 'points';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['label'] = 'Total Money';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['more_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['points']['format_plural'] = 0;
/* Field: User: Phone Number */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['id'] = 'field_phone';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['table'] = 'field_data_field_phone';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['field'] = 'field_phone';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['more_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_phone']['field_api_classes'] = 0;
/* Field: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['id'] = 'type_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['more_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['link_to_node'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['machine_name'] = 0;
/* Field: COUNT(Content: Type) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['label'] = 'Posts';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['more_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['element_label_colon'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['separator'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['format_plural'] = 0;
/* Field: Content: Author uid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['more_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['link_to_user'] = 1;
/* Field: Global: PHP */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['id'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['field'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['label'] = 'Reset';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['more_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['use_php_setup'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['php_output'] = ';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['use_php_click_sortable'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['php_click_sortable'] = '';
/* Field: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['label'] = 'Member Since';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['more_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['date_format'] = 'custom';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['custom_date_format'] = 'd/m/y';
/* Sort criterion: Userpoints total: Current total money */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['points']['id'] = 'points';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['points']['table'] = 'userpoints_total';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['points']['field'] = 'points';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['points']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'article' => 'article',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'post_count';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Post Count';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'user-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['block_description'] = 'user stats';
```

Comment: While providing an export is a great idea, unfortunately, eports like the one you have provided, are frequently not very useful, as other won't have the fields you use. To help us help you, such View's should be stripped of any custom fields first. (Unless they are absolutely necessary of course)

Comment: I understand. Ok let me simplify stuff. I have a user name field, The total number of posts the user has contributed to my drupal site. What I need is a way to include the date the first and last post were created. Please note am using  aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to do this with *one* Views display? It's trivial to do two displays, getting post dates, limiting to a single one, and then only overridding the sort order.

That would be

1. A *Field* on *Content: Post date*.
2. A *Contextual filter* on *User:uid*
3. A *Pager* limiting to a single hit
4. A *Sort* on *Content: Post date*.

The two displays will then override the Sort, one does ascending, one descending.

I can't think of a good way of doing it with a single display.

Comment: Ok Letharion two displays it is. Question is how do I get the dates of the first and last content the user created?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Wont that give me several post dates if the user has several articles? I am sorta trying to figure out drupal so please dont mind if it's a "dumb" question.

Comment: If you skip the pager, it will, but a "pager" limiting to a single hit, will solve that.

Comment: I guess it could but not really how I want it. Basically I want a summarized view eg a table with this list:
user Name |Total # of Posts|First Post Date | Last Post Date |
I already have the first two. The last two are presenting a headache.

Comment: Yes, I see. You should add that to the question, and I'll delete my answer instead, as I misunderstood you. What you want requires aggregation, which is a non-trivial topic.

Comment: Hey, just in case someone else is wondering how to do this. 1. Add a relationship content:author
2. Add Post date (label first post)
3. Aggregate this to Minimum
4. Add Post Date (label last post)
5. Aggregate this to Maximum.

Answer (score 1):

What you want, requires *aggregation*, that is, pulling out multiple rows of data, and summarizing it.

This is a non-trivial task, and you may find it difficult to accomplish with Views. It's possible that you will need to write the query yourself.

With that said, here's a link to some [Views aggregation related screencasts](http://nodeone.se/sv/learning-library?field_nc_learning_version_tid=All&field_nc_learning_concepts_tid=aggregation&field_nc_learning_modules_tid=Views).

Comment: Thank you sir, I figured it all out and felt rather dumb that I didnt before. Incase someone else is wondering how to do this...as Letharion says aggregate is the best option. For the first post use minimum for the last post use maximum.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation.:-(. Btw have any idea how to have published dates on my rss feeds? Currently I only get posted dates

Comment: You don't have enough to up-vote, but I believe you can always _accept_ answers :) The little check mark below the vote buttons do that.